# How to stop a stickied application from launching new instance if already running?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, desktop-environment, gnome-shell, application

I have a program that I have written in Python and added to Gnome with a desktop file.  When I click the stickied icon in Gnome to launch it, it duplicates the icon on my task bar and opens a new instance.  Other stickied applications just get a line under them.  When you click these other applications (like Chrome or Sublime Text) and they are already running, gnome just jumps to their window instead of launching a new instance.

Is this behavior something that I need to handle in my application, or is this something that Gnome can handle for me?  It is a PyQt4 application with a bash launcher if that makes a difference.

Edit-  Forgot to mention that I am running Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10 with Gnome 3.20.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this to work.

You need to add the key 'StartupWMClass' to your desktop entry.

StartupWMClass:  If specified, it is known that the application will map at least one window with the given string as its WM class or WM name hint.

Protocol information [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html) with more details [here](https://standards.freedesktop.org/startup-notification-spec/startup-notification-0.1.txt).

You can install xprop, run it and click the title bar to find out what class your application is.

Comment: thanks for coming back to update, exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the Python API, but this is related to [GtkApplication](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkApplication.html).

Read the [GtkApplication HowDoI](https://developer.gnome.org/GtkApplication/) wiki which says:

> GtkApplication defaults to applications being single-instance

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907897/proper-way-of-building-gtk3-applications-in-python).